# how spring mvc application scan configuration files under classpath

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Here i have a bean initialized `InitializingBean` in Spring MVC application. In order to register in `spring-servlet application context`, i two lines of code below:

```
    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext context;
    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        if (context.getParent() != null) {  // debug mode and add a breakpoint here, four times came here while application start up

        }
    }
```

Obviously, if four root application context initialized, some where error. but i really don't know why? 
***Here i make some assumption:***

- `contextConfigLocation` in `web.xml` file is **classpath*:**, and tomcat may detect multiple `applicationContext.xml` files under classpath jar files.(but spring xml files are really not locate in such jar files)
- **there are some configuration class in jar files** and who make spring mvc application scan the same jar file twice or more(but i did not find such class)

Maybe i'm totally error, hope someone can give me some hint and thanks.

Answer (score 0):

when starting your tomcat,the tags in your web.xml ,specificly,your codes will detect the configuration you wrote,initilized the spring container,such as,Application-Context.xml,if there is any  tag in this file , the Spring will add the file you write, for example, you write "Application-context-data.xml" in your  tag,the Spring container will initilized it !